# R: add text to an expression

Tags: r, formatting, plotmath

From `sfsmisc` package I have an expression and I want to add a text before that. How can I add text on an expression?

```
library(sfsmisc)
v <- pretty10exp(500)
title <- paste("some text ", v)
plot(1:5, 1:5, main = title)
```

This plots title as `some text 5 %*% 10^2` but not the formatted text.

Comment: @YannisVassiliadis: cNinja means as would be printed if it were interpreted as a plotmath expression. It's a mechanism a bit similar to TeX symbol parsing. See `?plotmath`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think if you use `parse` it will satisfy the R interpreter. `parse` returns an unevaluated 'expression'-classed value. You just need to make sure there are tildes (`~`) where you want spacing:

```
v <- pretty10exp(500)
title <- parse(text= paste("some ~text ~", v ) ) 
plot(1:5, 1:5, main = title)

title
#expression(some ~text ~ 5 %*% 10^2)
```

Expressions in R need to satisfy the parsing rules of the R language, e but the symbols or tokens don't need to refer to anything in particular in the applications since they will only be displayed "as is". So I decided to use `parse` as the constructor of the expression rather than trying to prepend text onto an existing expression. Between every token, there needs to be a separator. There can also be function-type use of parentheses "`(`" or square brackets "`[`", but they will need to be properly paired.

```
> expression( this won't work)   # because of the lack of separators
Error: unexpected symbol in "expression( this won"
> expression( this ~ won't *work)
+                           # because it fails to close after the single quote
> expression( this ~ won\'t *work)
Error: unexpected input in "expression( this ~ won\"
> expression( this ~ won\\'t *work)
Error: unexpected input in "expression( this ~ won\"
> expression( this ~ will *work)
expression(this ~ will * work)      # my first successful expression
> expression( this ~ will *(work)
+ but only if properly closed)     # parsing continued to 2nd line after parens.
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"expression( this ~ will *(work)
but"
> expression( this ~ will *(work)    # no error so far anyway
+ *but~only~if~properly~closed)
Error: unexpected '~' in:
"expression( this ~ will *(work)
*but~only~if~"
> expression( this ~ will *(work)
+ *but~only~'if'~properly~closed)
# At last ... acceptance
expression(this ~ will * (work) * but ~ only ~ "if" ~ properly ~ 
    closed)
```

That last one comes about because there are a few (very few) reserved words in R and `if` happens to be one of them. See `?Reserved`

Comment: +1 congrats you did it, I got stuck at `all.equal(noquote(paste("expression(", (paste('"some text"', v, sep = " ~ ")), ")")), expression("some text" ~ 5 %*% 10^2))`. I'd appreciate if you'd have a minute to add explanation to your answer.

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit it took me about 20 false starts. Nonetheless your congrats and upvote have just pushed me over the 200 rep/per day landmark and I'm that little bit closer to my "Legendary" badge, so I thank you. There're probably functions in the `rlang`-package that might also succeed.

Comment: Welcome! You also should earn a "rockbiter" batch, this was really a hard one! cheers

Comment: It's kind of weird what level of disconnect there is between the amount of time spent on answering a question and the number of votes offered. This one was pretty quick in the grand scheme of things. I worked all morning on this other one (and got 0): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49959319/string-wrapping-text-data-in-risk-table-in-surv-miner-for-ggplot2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do this automatically, but if you don't rely on this, you could do

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, main = expression("some text" ~ 5 %*% 10^2))
```

***yields:***

[image]